# how to set cylinder coordinates in Ursina Python

Tags: python

I need to set start and end cylinder coordinates. I can find an angle and rotate it but I need to use its coordinates so I have to know them.

```
from ursina import *

cyl = Entity(model=Cylinder(6, start=0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: When you look at the Ursina doc or type `help(Cylinder)`, which args are start and end cylinder coordinates? Edit your question to post us the output of `help(Cylinder)`

Comment: this is a documentation on Ursina https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#Entity

Comment: Ok here's the documentation on [Cylinder](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#Cylinder). So what's your question about start and end coords? When you say rotate the cylinder through an angle, which axis? If you could post a diagram or imag that would help.

Comment: @smci I know how to set end point for a line: line1 = Entity(model=Quad(scale=(3,1),thickness=3,vertices = [Vec3(0, 0, 0), Vec3(1, 1, 1)],radius = 0.2,segments=3,mode='line')). Vec3(0,0,0) is a start and Vec3(1,1,1) but how to set end coordinates for cylinder?